# Time format conversion using PGSQL query

Tags: php, postgresql, format, timestamp, pg

I would like to ask how to convert a 12 hour format time to 24 hour. For example I have a string 04:31:32 PM and I would like to convert it to 16:31:32 using pgsql query. Is this possible?

Please help.

Anyone?

Comment: fixed some grammatical error.

Comment: You puts a php tags but you never asking or mentioning anything about php.

Answer (score 0):

The `time` datatype is in 24-hour form by default, so you should just be able to cast it to a `time`:

```
test=> select '04:31:32 PM'::time;
   time
----------
 16:31:32
(1 row)
```